Game-theory optimality (GTO) background reading
Does somebody have a hint on the details behind GTO? When I google it, I only get links to handbooks on how to implement it. I would like to understand the concepts and math behind it.

Modern Poker Theory by Michael Acevedo is a mix of both practice and theory. I think it's a good starting point to understand the concepts. It has some toy game examples that demonstrate how equilibrium strategies work and tie them into the practical application in poker.

Can the person who downvoted this answer post a comment explaining why?
